# EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue with contact listener

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I am getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in my contact listener code. Below is the code:

Main object class (GameObjects) through which all objects are subclassed:

GameObjects.h:

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "CCNode.h"
#import "CCPhysicsSprite.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#include <math.h>

@interface GameObjects : CCNode {
    //b2Body* objectBody_;
}

-(b2Body*)getObjectBody;
-(void)objectsTouched:(GameObjects*)otherObject;
@end
```

GameObjects.mm (for now I just want to CCLOG to tell if it's working):

```
#import "GameObjects.h"

@implementation GameObjects

-(b2Body*)getObjectBody    {
}

-(void)objectsTouched:(GameObjects*)otherObject   {
   CCLOG(@"it's working");
}

@end
```

ContactListenerTest.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Box2D.h"
#import "Enemy.h"
#import "Sprite.h"
#import "GameObjects.h"



class ContactListenerTest : public b2ContactListener    {
public:

   b2World* world;
   void BeginContact(b2Contact* contact);
};
```

ContactListenerTest.mm:

```
#import "ContactListenerTest.h"

void ContactListenerTest:: BeginContact(b2Contact *contact)
{

    b2Fixture       *fixtureA = contact->GetFixtureA();
    b2Fixture       *fixtureB = contact->GetFixtureB();
    b2Body          *fixtureABody = fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body          *fixtureBBody = fixtureB->GetBody();

    GameObjects* spriteObject = (GameObjects*)fixtureABody->GetUserData();
    GameObjects* spriteObject2 = (GameObjects*)fixtureBBody->GetUserData();

    [spriteObject objectsTouched:spriteObject2];
    [spriteObject2 objectsTouched:spriteObject];

}
```

When I get the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error the following is printed in the console:

```
-[Enemy objectsTouched:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8558840
```

Enemy is one of the subclasses of GameObjects.

Answer (score 1):

Verify that the userdata object actually is of GameObjects class:

```
NSAssert1([spriteObject isKindOfClass:[GameObjects class]], 
          @"userdata %@ not a game object", spriteObject);
NSAssert1([spriteObject2 isKindOfClass:[GameObjects class]], 
          @"userdata 2 %@ not a game object", spriteObject2);
```

Comment: I just added the assertions and I got an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. The following was printed in the console:  `*** Assertion failure in virtual void ContactListenerTest::BeginContact(b2Contact *)(), /Users/codefreak/Documents/..../ContactListenerTest.mm:36
(lldb)`

Comment: ContactListenerTest.mm is a C++ class not an Objective-C class so NSCAssert1 should be used instead of NSAssert1.

Answer (score 0):

When you initialize the GameObject you should make sure that the UserData of the created body points to your GameObject. Something like this:

```
objectBody_->SetUserData(self);
```

Comment: does this have to be done for all the bodies. I only did it for one of the three bodies. Do I have to do this for all the bodies? Also, I did it immediately after creating the body.

Comment: Yes, all of them. If you're trying to access UserData but you didn't assign any value there then body->UserData might point anywhere. That could be the reason you're getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS.